# Error: Can not read property 'map' of undefined error In React Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After executing my React code, I gotthe following error message in the browser console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". here is my code

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    setData(jsonData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: If `data.map` is producing this error then `data` is `undefined`.  The state value is initialized to an empty array, so it must be getting set to `undefined` when fetching the data.  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the response from the server for this AJAX request?  Does it match what you expect?  Does it contain JSON?  When you debug this code, what is the observed runtime value of `jsonData`?

Comment: Before mapping through the data array always check whether the value is undefined or not.. I would suggest using a ternary operator to show a message to the user alerting them that data is empty/undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**You need to check first data should be defined when component renders **

 const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
 }, []);

 const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  setData(jsonData);
 };

 return (
    <div>
      {data && data.length?.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to handle possible errors in your request, so your app won't break. Like this:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    setData(jsonData);
  }
  catch (error) {
    // If the request returns an error...
    setData([]);
  }
}
```

If the error persists, probably your request has no error but is not returning anything (undefined).